# How to pass a python dataframe to a stored procedure

Tags: python, sql-server

I have a dataframe that has this info.

```
University Subject Colour
Melb       Math    Red
Melb       English Blue
Ottawa     Arts    Green
Ottawa     Math    Yellow
Sydney     Math    Black
Sydney     Arts    Red
```

there is around 1,000 records in this dataframe

I do not want to insert them one by one through a loop

What I am thinking is to pass the whole Dataframe to a stored procedure with a "**data-defined table type**" in `SQL Server`

so I can do the insert in one shot, how to do that?

Comment: Pandas has `to_sql()` method for dataframes.

Comment: @pavel to_sql() writes to a table directly, I want to send it to a stored procedure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python call sql-server stored procedure with table valued parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930062/python-call-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-table-valued-parameter)

Comment: @SMor this is not the same issue i am talking about. i want to pass dataframe as parameter if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Create Type** in SQL Server to define a input variable for a stored procedure **as table**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

```
CREATE TYPE LocationTableType AS TABLE   
    ( LocationName VARCHAR(50)  
    , CostRate INT );  
GO  

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_InsertLocation 
@Location AS LocationTableType 
AS
....
```