# Speed up Python executemany with "Insert or Ignore"-Statement

Tags: python, sql-server, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I am fairly new to pyodbc and ran in a problem where `executemany` takes a considerable long time. When benchmarking the script it took about 15 min to insert 962 rows into a table. I would like to speed this query up if possible.

I run the following script:

```py
cursor = conn.cursor()
parsed_json = get_parsed_json_Event_Log()
print(f'Gathering data from API found {len(parsed_json)} entries')

cursor.fast_executemany=True
cursor.executemany(f"""
                        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM {schema_name}.{table_name} WHERE id = ?)
                        INSERT INTO {schema_name}.{table_name}
                        SELECT  ?,
                                ?,
                                DATEADD(s, ?, '19700101 02:00:00:000'),
                                ?,
                                ?,
                                DATEADD(s, ?, '19700101 02:00:00:000'),
                                ?,
                                ?,
                                ?,
                                ?,
                                ?,
                                ?;""", parsed_json)
```

I am working with python 3.8.6 and an Azure SQL Server. The parsed JSON is in the specified sequence of sequences format, suggested by the pyodbc documentation. The cast date information in the `DATEADD` function is provided in terms of global seconds.

I tried to implement a `INSERT` OR `IGNORE INTO` statement, which I know is possible in SQLite. Unfortunately, I couldn't come up with an implementation for Azure SQL Server, thus had to default to an `IF NOT EXISTS` statement.

It would be awesome if one could help me to speed up the script or refine the statement for faster execution.

Comment: Is the table indexed on `id`? And have you considered using a table parameter, or doing bulk insert to a temp table, and doing a single joined update from that? I hope you aren't taking `schema_name` and `table_name` from user input or a download over the net, because that leaves you open to SQL injection

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, 
`id` in this regard is the primary key of my table. The table itself is not indexed. As far as i understood bulk insert, it is only used if one wants to insert a file into a database? In my example the data is stored in a python list, directly fetched from the mentioned api. Could you elaborate how i could use bulk insert in this scenario? 
`schema_name` and `table_name` are specified in the driver method of this script and are thereby hardcoded, while the script is executed using cron.
Thanks for your fast answer :)

Comment: If `id` is the primary key of the table, I'm assuming it is a clustered index, please confirm.  I don't know Python well, but this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930062/python-call-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-table-valued-parameter seems to have info on using a table parameter. Bulk insert: sorry the term is actuallly bulk copy, which uses a similar fast-insert method, but a TVP may be simpler

Comment: Why not use procedures?

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, the Primary Key is NonClustered and Not Enforced. Would it be beneficial to change it to clustered performance wise? I just quickly read up on the concept, as the initial creation of the table was out of my scope. 
Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: @JasonPan, could you elaborate how a procedure would increase performance here? 
Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: https://bertwagner.com/posts/are-stored-procedures-faster-than-stand-alone-queries/

Comment: If you query via that column most of the time then you should cluster on it. And a PK that is not enforced may as well not exist, why wouldn't you enforce it? @JasonPan Or in other words, no it doesn't make any difference in the vast majority of cases to use a procedure. TVPs can be used in ad-hoc batches also

Comment: @Charlieface, thank you for your patience and the dedication to help me! I really appreciate it. Since i am fairly new to the company i wrote this code for i will ask my advisor why the creation of the table was made that way and will come back to you on monday (next time i am at work). I will also test out to what extend clustering on the id column will help to increase performance, since your were right in that i will iterate over the id column most of the time.

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, i just tried your suggestion and it reduced the execution time around 1 min, which is awesome! :) Also there was no specific point why the table was initially created that way, except that it was an easy fix to an error according to my advisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made several attempts to speed up the query and gathered some insights which in wanted to share with everybody who may encounters the same issue:

Takeaways:

1. When using Azure SQL Server always try to use the `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...)` Statement instead of `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`, as it performs about 350% faster (when benchmarked for the described problem and used syntax).

   - The main reason why i used `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` was because of the specific `DATEADD()` Cast, as you can't do that without explicitly declaring variables in Azure SQL Server.
2. You can skip the `DATEADD()` in the given example if you cast the provided time to python `datetime`. If you choose this option make sure to not use literal strings when inserting the data to your SQL Table. Besides bad practice as adressed by @Charlieface, `PYODBC` has no built-in logic for that datatype when using the string-literal input (sequence-of-sequence input structure has no problem here)
3. The `IF NOT EXISTS` Statement is really expensive. Try to omit it if possible. A simple workaround, if you depend on preserving your table historically, is to create a second table that is newly created and then insert from that table to your original where no match was found. Here you can depend on your native SQL implementation instead of the PYODBC implementation. This way was by far the fastest.

The different design choices resulted in the following performance improvements:

- `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` vs `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...)`: 350%
- Leveraging a second table and native SQL support: 560%