# Executing an SQL update statement from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

Context: I am using MSSQL, pandas, and pyodbc.

Steps:

- Obtain dataframe from query using pyodbc (no problemo)
- Process columns to generate the context of a new (but already existing) column
- Fill an auxilliary column with UPDATE statements (i.e. `UPDATE t SET t.value = df.value FROM dbo.table t where t.ID = df.ID`)

Now how do I execute the sql code in the auxilliary column, without looping through each row?

**sample data**

The first two columns are obtained by querying `dbo.table`, the third columns exists but is empty in the database. The fourth column only exists in the dataframe to prepare the SQL statement that would correspond to updating `dbo.table`

| ID | raw | processed | strSQL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | lorum.ipsum@test.com | lorum ipsum | UPDATE t SET t.processed = 'lorum ipsum' FROM dbo.table t WHERE t.ID = 1 |
| 2 | rumlo.sumip@test.com | rumlo sumip | UPDATE t SET t.processed = 'rumlo sumip' FROM dbo.table t WHERE t.ID = 2 |
| 3 | ... | ... | ... |

I would like to execute the SQL script in each row in an efficient manner.

Comment: can you porvide sample data. your question will be easy to understand

Comment: Looping through the DataFrame rows and issuing individual UPDATE statements for each table row will be very inefficient. It would be much faster to dump the two columns to a list of tuples as `[(processed, id),(processed, id),…]` (note the order of the columns) and then use `crsr.executemany("UPDATE t SET t.processed=? WHERE t.ID=?", my_list_of_tuples)`. Be sure to call `crsr.fast_executemany = True` first for best performance.

Comment: For even better performance, use a Table valued Parameter, or create a temporary table and Bulk Copy into it. Then do a single joined update

Comment: @Charlieface I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930062/python-call-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-table-valued-parameter for example. A TVP is basically a readonly table variable that you can use to do a joined update. There is no need to loop anything, just a single `update t ... from yourtable t join @yourTVP p on ...`

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](http://XYproblem.info). Why are you stopped ING SQL statements in a table to be run? Is the process your using to insert that data got a extremely good parses on it to stop the insertion of malicious code?

Comment: @Larnu I am indeed asking about help with a possible solution to another problem. While your sentences confuse me, I think you are talking about inserting user input. However it's not the case.
my problem consists out of processing a large table (>10m rows) in a way that is not possible with only SQL. That's why I'm using python, a language that i'm comfortable with. The auxiliary column is only a possible solution. Using execute many as Gord Thompson mentioned is also possibile. Do you have any other plausible solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I recommended `.executemany()` in a comment to the question, a subsequent comment from @Charlieface suggested that a table-valued parameter (TVP) would provide even better performance. I didn't think it would make that much difference, but I was wrong.

For an existing table named MillionRows

```
ID  TextField
--  ---------
 1  foo
 2  bar
 3  baz
…
```

and example data of the form

```py
num_rows = 1_000_000
rows = [(f"text{x:06}", x + 1) for x in range(num_rows)]
print(rows)
# [('text000000', 1), ('text000001', 2), ('text000002', 3), …]
```

my test using a standard `executemany()` call with `cnxn.autocommit = False` and `crsr.fast_executemany = True`

```py
crsr.executemany("UPDATE MillionRows SET TextField = ? WHERE ID = ?", rows)
```

took about 180 seconds (3 minutes).

However, by creating a user-defined table type

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.TextField_ID AS TABLE 
(
    TextField nvarchar(255) NULL, 
    ID int NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

and a stored procedure

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[mr_update]
@tbl dbo.TextField_ID READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE MillionRows SET TextField = t.TextField
    FROM MillionRows mr INNER JOIN @tbl t ON mr.ID = t.ID
END
```

when I used

```py
crsr.execute("{CALL mr_update (?)}", (rows,))
```

it did the same update in approximately 80 seconds (less than half the time).